# How Can I Create App Update Widget Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How Can I create update widget like Soundcloud
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBMvR.png)

I tried to use Slide Up Panel and open app Using Webview but not like Sound cuz I want to remove Store App Bar and Nav Bar But I can't
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtwsR.jpg)

Comment: Check this package you don't have to manually hardcode the UI and logic for this. https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.